# socket duplex communication simultaneous or not?

Tags: sockets, bidirectional

When I have a duplex connection between A and B, does it allow data to be sent from both directions at the same time? Or when data is sent in one direction, the other direction is blocked?

For example, if A and B both have 5 packets to send to the other, each packet takes 1 second to send, and they start to send at the same time.  How long does it take to finish both sending? 5 seconds(no blocking) or 10 seconds(blocking)?

Comment: You need to define whether you're talking about full duplex or half duplex, which turns on precisely this distinction.

Comment: Thanks EJP, I think you've answered my question, as I was not aware full vs half duplex difference.  I believe socket library in modern programming language should all support full duplex? So my question is answered.